# Can a lambda be used to change a List's values in-place ( without creating a new list)?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, lambda, java-8

I am trying to determine the correct way of changing all the values in a `List` using the new lambdas feature in the upcoming release of **Java 8** without creating a `**new** List`.

This pertains to times when a `List` is passed in by a caller and needs to have a function applied to change all the contents to a new value. For example, the way `Collections.sort(list)` changes a list in-place.

What is the easiest way given this transforming function, and this starting list, to apply the function to all the values in the original list without making a new list?

```
String function(String s){ 
    return s.toUppercase(); // or something else more complex
}

List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Bob", "Steve", "Jim", "Arbby");
```

The usual way of applying a change to all the values in-place was this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.set(i, function( list.get(i) );
}
```

Does lambdas and Java 8 offer:

- an easier and more expressive way?
- a way to do this without setting up all the scaffolding of the `for(..)` loop?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Bob", "Steve", "Jim", "Arbby");
    list.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase);
```

Comment: That's not lambda.

Answer (score 2):

With a popular library [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) you can create a computing view on the list which doesn't allocate memory for a new array, i.e.:

```
upperCaseStrings = Lists.transform(strings, String::toUpperCase)
```

<s>A better solution is proposed by @StuartMarks, however, I am leaving this answer as it allows to also change a generic type of the collection.</s>

---

Another option is to declare a static method like `mutate` which takes list and lambda as a parameter, and import it as a static method i.e.:

```
mutate(strings, String::toUpperCase);
```

A possible implementation for `mutate`:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public static  List mutate(List list, Function function) {
    List objList = list;

    for (int i = 0; i
```

Comment: Does the Guava Lists.transform(...) actually modify the values of the original list? Or is it a changed view of the original list? For your `mutate` function. That should work. too bad Java did not include that as a default static method for `Lists` or on all lists.

Comment: It's an immutable computing view of an original list, it does not modify it. It's ok for a single pass over a list, but might be not for multiple passes.

Comment: Interesting approach of changing the type of the list. You could make `objList` be of type `List<T>` and move the `@SuppressWarnings` directly onto that declaration; this avoids accidentally suppressing unrelated warnings elsewhere in the method. However, I'm not sure this is a good idea. The `mutate` function looks like it consumes a List<F> and returns a List<T>. I think most programmers would be surprised to discover that it returns the **same** list. (The name `mutate` is a clue, though.) I'd say it's preferable to use streams to create and return a new `List<T>`.

Comment: Yeah, this is controversial. Seems to be a normal thing in dynamic-typed languages and absolutely uncommon for static languages. Perhaps initially declaring a list as `List<?>` for this purpose is a better way to go. I will gray it out.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have overlooked `forEach`, which can be used to mutate the elements of a `List`. Of course, that doesn't cover your use case entirely—it won't help if your elements are immutable or if you want to replace them completely. [edit: the next sentence relates to streams, not to collections as specified in the question] There is a good reason why you can't do those operations: they aren't parallel-friendly (this actually applies to `forEach` also) and the Stream API strongly discourages the use of sequential-only operations.

Comment: `forEach` on a List only allows the elements to be iterated. It does not allow the changing of the value within the list.

Comment: The -1 is unjustified. The OP's question asked about "transforming all the values" in the list. This is ambiguous. It could mean either 1) mutating each list element in-place, or 2) replacing each element with a different element. This answer addresses the first cast.

Comment: @StuartMarks The title is very clear "change a List's values in-place" and the example given is explicitly clear on "The usual way of applying a change to all the values in-place".

Comment: Way is changing the value of a stream's contents not parallel friendly?

Comment: Very reasonable question, given the way I phrased that. Of course, transforming the value of stream elements is exactly what the map operation does. I was thinking about changing stream values in-place, rather than passing on transformed values. That would need a mechanism outside of the standard streams framework. But that scenario is off-topic, and looking back I don't think my comment was helpful.